# Warning status issue in jmeter result table

Tags: jmeter, warnings

I have to do load testing for a web based application. I am getting status as warning the results table. My request contains the URL and the path as /. I have passed username and password in the parameters section. Even after tried many times still it shows status as warning.

I have also tried using Proxyserver address, port, user name and password ...still no luck..

Please help me on this.

Comment: Can you please clarify what the problem is? "shows status as warning" is not very descriptive. What do you expect to see? What do you actually see? Do you get any warning descriptions? Please take a moment to read through [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You can always [edit] your question.

Comment: I would expect to see the status as 'Success' , I am not getting any warning descriptions.

Comment: you can configure jmeter to save the response results which would help you pinpoint the exact cause of the problem.

Comment: Hello, any feedback on answer ? If it is ok you should accept it and upvote so that it's helpful to others. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you get a Warning status, this means that JMeter detected a response code > 399.

There can be a lot of reasons for this, examples:

- Wrong URL : 404
- Error : 500

To have more details on it, add a [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and inspect all tabs to see:

- Request : What you are sending (headers / Cookies / body)
- Response : What you are getting (headers / Cookies / body)

Then fix your HTTP request by comparing request in browser with what you have build.

Alternatively, use JMeter [recording](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) feature.

To see all ways to debug a script, have a look at this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) where sample chapter explains lot of ways.

Answer (score 0):

If you get warning status that means your entered URL contains https:// part which means your given URL working with HTTP protocol.
Remove https:// part from
 - HTTP Request Defaults
 - HTTP Request 
So replace https:// part by WWW and try again